# page not visible in portrait orientation

Tags: android, html, css

I am trying to develop a responsive site.
I've been testing several @media on my PC and so far so good.

The problem started wen I passed to my Android Smartphone.
For some reason, the site is presented as it should be in Landscape orientation, but in Portrait orientation a blank page is presented.

I have tested in Firefox and Chrome and the problem is the same.
I do have noticed that if I chose the "reader view" the content of the page can be read, so the page is being loaded, plus, I installed a HTML source code viewer and the page is fully loaded.

I have tested on two different Android Smartphones, with the same resolution: 540 x 960 px

You can find the page here:
http://www.chazard.eu/teste/cspreguengogrande

and here is my css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

html,
body{
    min-height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:-10;
}

#Background{
    position:absolute;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    z-index:1;
}

#Background_Left{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    background:url(images/background_left.jpg) fixed;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left;
    background-size:contain;
}

#Background_Right{
    float:right;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    background:url(images/background_right.jpg) fixed;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
    background-size:contain;
}

#mainDIV{
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:1000px;
    min-height:100%;
    z-index:10;
}

#BotoesContainer{
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    background:url(images/banner.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
}

#ConteudoContainer{
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:70px;
}

/* --------------------------------------------------
Smartphone / Tablet View Port < 960 px width Horizontal
 --------------------------------------------------*/

@media (max-device-width: 960px) and (orientation: landscape){
    #mainDIV{
        width:600px;
    }
}

/* --------------------------------------------------
Smartphone / Tablet View Port < 540 px width Horizontal
 --------------------------------------------------*/

@media (max-device-width: 540px) and (orientation: portrait){
    #mainDIV{
        width:520px;
    }

    #Background{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

I have removed some non-essencial css.

Any advise?

Answer (score 1):

Use `max-width` instead of `max-device-width`. Also, you need to probably use the media query with `max-width: 980px`, if its a desktop site.

*Reason*:

`max-width` refers to the width of the viewport and can be used to target specific sizes or orientations in conjunction with `max-height`.

`max-device-width` refers to the viewport size of the **device** regardless of orientation, current scale or resizing.

Comment: Probably some more change is required. Now background is visible but not the text.

Comment: Aparently this does not work.
I have changed
media (max-device-width: 540px) and (orientation: portrait)
to
media (max-width: 540px) and (orientation: portrait)

and now the @media is not even run

Comment: Only the background is showen because the "media" is not being run. I get the same exact result is I remove the "media". Note that the "media" rule says that the Background should be removed ("display:none").

Comment: But on desktop if you see with max-width, its getting applied correctly. On reducing the size of browser "background" is hidden and mainDiv width is 520px.

Comment: It only works on PC browser if I set my "media" as: media (max-width: 540px). If I had "orientation: landscape" it does'nt work for obvious reasons. Still not working on Smartphone